# Access USB device of another machine as if it was locally plugged?

Tags: networking, usb

I would like to use, on server A, an USB webcam that is physically plugged on server B.

Is there a way to *mount* the `/dev/video0` of server B on server A (as `/dev/video0`, or `/dev/video1`, etc.).

Both servers are running Debian Wheezy and can communicate via local network.

Comment: For video you should use a streaming server.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [USB/IP](http://usbip.sourceforge.net/) project.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Braiam This critique doesn't make any sense in this case as the answer is to use a certain software which is mentioned by name. Thus in contrast to the typical case the link does not provide the answer here. The answer is in the text and the link just shows where to find the software or read more about it.